# What are the Properties of a Matrix $X$ such that $X\times (X^tX)^{-1}\times X^t = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

can you please help me in the following question:

What are the Properties of a Matrix $X$ such that  $X\times (X^tX)^{-1}\times X^t = I$

$X$ is not necessarily a square Matrix.

I am interested in such matrix and would appreciate any guidance on where to read about this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are exactly those square $X $ that are invertible. It works even in the complex case if we replace "transpose" with "adjoint" .

For square $X $, we have that $X^*X $ is invertible if and only if  $X $ is invertible, and in such case $X (X^*X)^{-1}X^*=I $.

When $X $ is not square with $m $ rows and $n $ columns: if $m <n $, then $X^*X $ cannot be invertible ($n\times n $, with rank at most $m $). If  $m>n $ with $X^*X $ invertible, the rank of $X (X^*X )^{-1}X^*$ is at most $n $, so it cannot equal $I_m $.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer. can you please guide me to a reference where i can read more about it... I have tried several matrices, but for each matrix i could not achieve this... all matrices had their X*X being invertable....

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you are asking. This is a straightforward computation; what kind of "reference" do you expect? And if $X^*X $ is invertible, the equality holds, so again not sure what you mean.

Comment: I have been looking into some artificial Matrices with NxP dimension (these are the X, each). While the inverse of X*X exists, none of each example X gave X/(X'X)X' = I. so i am not sure how to select matrix X that satisfies this. in other word, even if the inverse of X'X exists, I would not necesserily have X/(X'X)X' = I.

Comment: You are right, my computation assumes that $X $ is square.  I'll edit a little later.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Glad I could help.